# degree symbol not being rendered by vue component

Tags: vue.js

I have a vue component which displays a gauge.  I need to include units on the display and have this as one of the props of the component.  However, because there are a number of gauges with different formatting it is all stored in a vuex store that reads its settings from an API.  This all works nicely apart from when I want to bring special symbols (such as degree signs) across.  The vuex object is storing the formatting object as:

```
{"min":0,"max":50,"dp":1,"units":"&deg;C"}
```

and I use it in my component as follows:

```
            <svg-gauge v-else
                v-bind:g-value="device.value"
                v-bind:g-min="device.format.min"
                v-bind:g-max="device.format.max"
                v-bind:g-decplace="device.format.dp"
                v-bind:g-units="device.format.units"
            >
```

The problem is that this simply displays °C rather than a degree symbol.  If I hard code the last line as

```
g-units="&deg;C"
```

It all works as expected.  I suspect it is that I am having to use v-bind to pass the property and this is messing things up.  Is there a way to ensure that v-bind is treating my characters as I would like?

EDIT: Here is the svg-gauge component template where the units are actually rendered.

```
<template>
    <b-row>
        <b-card no-body class="bg-dark text-light border-0" align="center">
            <b-card-body class="m-0 pt-0 pb-0">
                <h5><slot name="title">Title</slot></h5>
                <div class="row mini-gauge pt-3" align="center">
                    <vue-svg-gauge
                        class="mini-gauge"
                        :start-angle="-90"
                        :end-angle="90"
                        :value="gValue"
                        :separator-step="0"
                        :min="gMin"
                        :max="gMax"
                        base-color="#595959"
                        :gauge-color="[{ offset: 0, color: '#347AB0'}, { offset: 100, color: '#D10404'}]"
                        :scale-interval="5"
                    >
                        <div style="line-height: 11rem">{{gValue.toFixed(gDecplace)}} {{gUnits}}</div>
                    </vue-svg-gauge>
                </div>
                <div class="row mini-gauge">
                    <div class="col" align="left">{{gMin}}</div>
                    <div class="col" align="right">{{gMax}}</div>
                </div>
            </b-card-body>
        </b-card>
    </b-row>
</template>
```

Comment: Hi again ;) May you add how you display the `g-units` prop in your svg-gauge component?

Comment: @Raffobaffo, thanks, I have edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line to have a span with a v-html. Then in the v-html pass the gUnits prop

```
 <div style="line-height: 11rem">
     {{gValue.toFixed(gDecplace)}} 
      <span v-html="gUnits"></span> 
 </div>
```

You can find the reason by looking [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML).

Hope this helps!